# Looping through Text Boxes in .NET

Tags: .net

I have pretty basic question in #C. I have some text boxes named TextBox1,TextBox2,....,TextBox10 on web form and I want them to access in loop , something like

```
For(var count=1;count<10;count++) {
    TextBox+count.tostring().text="something"
}
```

Can we do eval() like JavaScript?

Comment: Just create and initialize a `List<TextBox>` in your constructor so you don't have to go hunting them down later.

Comment: Jeff, Yes I do for the answers which helps me.

Comment: Hans, Can you please share some code?

Comment: @Rishi: Out of 49 questions, you've only had about 12 responses that have been helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to do this on the server side then you could use Page.Controls (or some other container where your textbox objects are located). For example:

```
foreach(var ctrl in Page.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        var myTxtControl = ctrl as TextBox;
        myTxtControl.Text = "Some text goes here";
    }
}
```

but if you can do this on the client side it would be even better and more interactive than sending data back to server and processing it over there.

Javascript solution using jQuery might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButtonText").click(function() {
        $("input[type='text']").val("something");
    });
});
```

Comment: Huske, I'm looking for client side solution. Since they are .net text box controls so not getting right logic to add code.

Answer (score 0):

As it's web form, you can just set them same class, and pick that class using JavaScript. At least this is mostly used approach.

Comment: Dejan,They are .NET controls. Please elaborate about your suggestion.

Comment: There's then better answer bellow my post (from user Huske). What I meant is, if you want to parse on client side, in JavaScript, you can just add same class to TextBox HTML object, and set the value (use JavaScript selector to get object with class name 'example' and set it value 'something'). That's what I understood from your code snippet. But, if you want then to pass it as array to your controller code, you can initialize List<TextBox> and parse it like a list there. Or if none of those, then check the post below mine (as mine concept is mostly working using ASP.NET MVC).